# How to Connect Mobile App to different servers

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Currently we have an Xamarin iOS app which connects to different servers based on bundle ID. For example: If the Bundle ID ends with .Dev, App connects to development Server. If Bundle ID ends with .QA, App connects to QA Server. If the Bundle ID ends with .Mobile, App connects to Production Server etc. Right now we are re-writing this App in Xamarin Forms to support Android devices too. What is best way to connect this new App to different servers ?

Please provide an example if any available.

Comment: I think you can do the same, but you have to create a [`DependencyService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to communicate with the native side

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the App ID to do that, it's unwise to have a condition which would only be  executed using the same path through out the life cycle of the app, plus it has the potential to unleash hell on you if one of your team just forgot to change the App ID before publishing -remember that you now also need to manage two app IDs not only one-

The best way in my opinion to do what you are trying to is using the compiler If directive in the similar manner to the one mentioned below

```
#if Debug
string baseUrl = "http://mydev-server.com;
#endIf

#if Release
string baseUrl = "http://myprod-server.com
#endIf

#if MyCustomConfiguration
string baseUrl = "http://mycustom-server.com
#endif
```

make as many of those as you need